# T-SQL: Combining rows based on another table

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-server-2016

I am seeking to alter a table content based on information of another table using a stored procedure. To make my point (and dodge my rusty English skills) I created the following simplification.

I have a table with fragment amounts of the form

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[obtained_fragments] ->
fragment   amount
22         42
76         7
101        31
128        4
177        22
212        6
```

and a table that lists all possible combinations to combine these fragments to other fragments.

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[possible_combinations] ->
fragment   consists_of_f1   f1_amount_needed   consists_of_f2   f2_amount_needed
1001       128              1                  22               3
1004       151              1                  101              12
1012       128              1                  177              6
1047       212              1                  76               4
```

My aim is to alter the first table so that all possible fragment combinations are performed, leading to

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[obtained_fragments] ->
fragment   amount
22         30
76         3
101        31
177        22
212        5
1001       4
1047       1
```

In words, combined fragments are added to the table based on [dbo].[possible_combinations], and the amount of needed fragments is reduced. Depleted fragments are removed from the table.

How do I achieve this fragment transformation in an easy way? I started writing a while loop, checking if sufficient fragments are available, inside of a for loop, interating through the fragment numbers. However, I am unable to come up with a functional amount check and begin to wonder if this is even possible in T-SQL this way.

*The code doesn't have to be super efficient since both tables will always be smaller than 200 rows.*

**It is important to note that it doesn't matter which combinations are created.**

It might come in handy that [f1_amount_needed] always has a value of 1.

### UPDATE

Using the solution of iamdave, which works perfectly fine as long I don't touch it, I receive the following error message:

**Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.**

I barely changed anything really. Is there a chance that using existing tables with more than the necessary columns instead of declaring the tables (as iamdave did) makes this difference?

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Binding_ID int, Exists_of_Binding_ID_2 int, Exists_of_Pieces_2 int, Binding1 int, Binding2 int);

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN

    DELETE @t

    INSERT INTO @t
        SELECT TOP 1
             k.Binding_ID
            ,k.Exists_of_Binding_ID_2
            ,k.Exists_of_Pieces_2
            ,g1.mat_Binding_ID AS Binding1
            ,g2.mat_Binding_ID AS Binding2

        FROM [dbo].[vwCombiBinding] AS k

        JOIN [leer].[sandbox5] AS g1
        ON k.Exists_of_Binding_ID_1 = g1.mat_Binding_ID AND g1.Amount >= 1

        JOIN [leer].[sandbox5] AS g2
        ON k.Exists_of_Binding_ID_2 = g2.mat_Binding_ID AND g2.Amount >= k.Exists_of_Pieces_2

        ORDER BY k.Binding_ID

    IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @t) = 1
        BEGIN

        UPDATE g
        SET Amount = g.Amount +1
        FROM [leer].[sandbox5] AS g

        JOIN @t AS t
        ON g.mat_Binding_ID = t.Binding_ID

        INSERT INTO [leer].[sandbox5]
        SELECT
             t.Binding_ID
            ,1
        FROM @t AS t
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM [leer].[sandbox5] AS g WHERE g.mat_Binding_ID = t.Binding_ID);

        UPDATE g
        SET Amount = g.Amount - 1
        FROM [leer].[sandbox5] AS g

        JOIN @t AS t
        ON g.mat_Binding_ID = t.Binding1

        UPDATE g
        SET Amount = g.Amount - t.Exists_of_Pieces_2
        FROM [leer].[sandbox5] AS g

        JOIN @t AS t
        ON g.mat_Binding_ID = t.Binding2

        END
    ELSE
        BREAK
END

SELECT * FROM [leer].[sandbox5]
```

Comment: ***It is important to note that it doesn't matter which combinations are created.***  --  Are you sure about that?  From a business logic point of view that seems like it is probably an important element of the design here, especially if there needs to be an order to the fragment creation or a prioritisation of certain creations over others.

Comment: @iamdave Hi Dave! Yes, it may seem relevant. Yet, the value v drawn from combined fragments cf is v(cf) = v(f1) * a(f1) + v(f2) * a(f2) with amount a. Thanks for your further inquiry.

Comment: I think you have a typo in your `obtained_fragments` table?  `177` jumps from `amount = 22` to `amount = 23` which I think shouldn't be possible?

Comment: Yes, thanks again :-) I corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `while` loop that contains several statements to handle your iterative data updates.  As you need to make changes based on a re-assessment of your data each iteration this *has* to be done in a loop of some kind:

```
declare @f table(fragment int,amount int);
insert into @f values (22 ,42),(76 ,7 ),(101,31),(128,4 ),(177,22),(212,6 );

declare @c table(fragment int,consists_of_f1 int,f1_amount_needed int,consists_of_f2 int,f2_amount_needed int);
insert into @c values (1001,128,1,22,3),(1004,151,1,101,12),(1012,128,1,177,6),(1047,212,1,76,4);

declare @t table(fragment int,consists_of_f2 int,f2_amount_needed int,fragment1 int,fragment2 int);

while 1 = 1
begin
    -- Clear out staging area
    delete @t;

    -- Populate with the latest possible combination
    insert into @t
    select top 1 c.fragment
                ,c.consists_of_f2
                ,c.f2_amount_needed
                ,f1.fragment as fragment1
                ,f2.fragment as fragment2
    from @c as c
        join @f as f1
            on c.consists_of_f1 = f1.fragment
                and f1.amount >= 1
        join @f as f2
            on c.consists_of_f2 = f2.fragment
                and f2.amount >= c.f2_amount_needed
    order by c.fragment;

    -- Update fragments table if a new combination can be made
    if (select count(1) from @t) = 1
        begin

            -- Update if additional fragment
            update f
            set amount = f.amount + 1
            from @f as f
                join @t as t
                    on f.fragment = t.fragment;

            -- Insert if a new fragment
            insert into @f
            select t.fragment
                  ,1
            from @t as t
            where not exists(select null
                             from @f as f
                             where f.fragment = t.fragment
                            );

            -- Update fragment1 amounts
            update f
            set amount = f.amount - 1
            from @f as f
                join @t as t
                    on f.fragment = t.fragment1;

            -- Update fragment2 amounts
            update f
            set amount = f.amount - t.f2_amount_needed
            from @f as f
                join @t as t
                    on f.fragment = t.fragment2;

        end
    else    -- If no new combinations possible, break the loop
        break
end;

select *
from @f;
```

Output:

```
+----------+--------+
| fragment | amount |
+----------+--------+
|       22 |     30 |
|       76 |      3 |
|      101 |     31 |
|      128 |      0 |
|      177 |     22 |
|      212 |      5 |
|     1001 |      4 |
|     1047 |      1 |
+----------+--------+
```

Comment: When god distributed cerebral matter you stood in the first row

Comment: @MichelleTurner  Happy to help :)

Comment: Dave, I get the error message 'Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.' At first I thought T-SQL doesn't like the "DELETE @t" command, but in a seperate query it flawlessly does its job. Do you have an idea what I did wrong there?

Comment: You have a mismatch between the number of columns you are trying to `insert` and the number of columns returned by the `select` you are trying to `insert` from.  I would recommend adding an explicit column list to any of the `insert` statements above.  If you are still having difficulty, can you add your script as you are using it to your question?

Comment: As you suggested I added my script to the question; Is there specific information I need to add concerning the tables '[dbo].[vwCombiBinding]' and '[leer].[sandbox5]'?

Comment: @MichelleTurner  Looks like you need to specify which columns are being inserted into for the `INSERT INTO [leer].[sandbox5]` statement, as it looks like the columns in that table are named slightly differently to the result of your `select`.  I think you'll just need to change it to something like `INSERT INTO [leer].[sandbox5](mat_Binding_ID, Amount)`

Comment: It works perfectly alright with that added, thank you SO MUCH again Dave! :)

Comment: @MichelleTurner  No worries, glad you got it working :)